# PHP-isset for loop not working to check unknown number of buttons

Tags: php, html, loops, for-loop, isset

In this .php file, in the html body, I generate an unordered list with an unknown number of items: $num_files (1 list item for each file in the directory).

End up with an unordered list of files in the directory with a "view" button for each one.

When the user clicks the view button for a specific file (a specific list item), it should redirect.

No matter which button I press, nothing happens.

```
[some stuff up here]

<ul class="center">
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
<?php
if($num_files==0) exit;
$i = 0;
$ii=0;
while ($i < $num_files) {
    $ii=$i+2;
    echo "<li> $user_filenames[$ii] </li>";
    $id = trim("view".$i);
    echo '<input type="submit" id=$id name=$id value="view">';
    $i=$i+1;
}?>
</form>
</ul>

<?php
    $x=0;
    $xx=0;
    while ($x < $num_files) {
        $var = trim("view".$x);
        if(isset($_POST[$var])){
            $xx = $x+2;
            $_SESSION['current_file'] = $user_filenames[$xx];
            header("Location: view_file.php");
            exit;
        }
        $x=$x+1;
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

It's worth noting that when I change the code to the following, then it successfully redirects when I press any button (but will only redirect with a predetermined $user_filenames[x] element, and can't distinguish among buttons).

```
<ul class="center">
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
<?php
if($num_files==0) exit;
$i = 0;
$ii=0;
while ($i < $num_files) {
    $ii=$i+2;
    echo "<li> $user_filenames[$ii] </li>";
    echo '<input type="submit" id="view" name="view" value="view">';
    $i=$i+1;
}?>
</form>
</ul>

<?php
        if(isset($_POST['view'])){
            $_SESSION['current_file'] = $user_filenames[2];
            header("Location: view_file.php");
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check what's in `$_POST`, you might also want to add quotes in `name=$id` to start with some valid HTML code

Comment: Got it. Unfortunately I'm still getting the issues, even with the proper html.

Answer (score 0):

When you view source are the name and id attributes of this correct?

```
input type="submit" id=$id name=$id value="view"
```

Comment: I don't think  the if id ever evaluating to to true.  Since the echo is in single quotes $id is being echoed as $id and not the value of ot he variable.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php  Also make sure that $var = trim("view".$x); matches the value of name here input type="submit" id=$id name=$id value="view"

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
echo '<input type="submit" id=$id name=$id value="view">';
```

instead of this (which you said works)

```
echo '<input type="submit" id="view" name="view" value="view">';
```

which makes sense, because judging by your code the upper one should turn into:

```
<input type="submit" id=someid name=someid value="view"
```

That's invalid html. You need to make sure your generated code contains quotation marks too.

I suggest you also try out "firebug" for firefox. using that you would have noticed scrambled html without even thinking about it.

This would be one variant of fixing your problem:

```
$id = "'". trim("view".$i)."'";
```

Comment: Got it. Unfortunately I'm still getting the issues, even with the proper html.

Comment: what issue? click not working? you should post your generated html btw. maybe that sheds light on the matter